# See Facebook friends invited to use iOS app using Facebook SDK 4.0?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am developing an `iOS` app (not a game) that connects to a back end, where users are logged in with `Facebook` and can invite other users to events in the app, from his/her Facebook friend list.

I therefore need to know when an invited user log's in with `Facebook`, if the new user has already been invited to an event in the app. The back end stores all the users with their `facebookUserIDs` and is ready to track people that are invited to the events.

I have found several options for people to invite their Facebook friends to use the app BUT apparently **none of them returns a list of the Facebook friends that was invited**.
The app needs to know who was invited so it can show the invitees in the app BEFORE they download the app and log's in with `Facebook`.

The app is coded in `Swift` with Deployment Target 7.0 using the latest iOS `Facebook SDK 4.1`, and the intention is to use Facebook API's that have not been deprecated.

**Possible options:**

- `App Invites` - Would be a good option, but I can't figure out a way to get a callback with the people that was invited (their `facebookUserID`, name, whatever)?
- `Share link or photo` - Can't find a way to get a callback with people by using this either? Has a `ref` attribute but don't know how to use that.
- `Message Dialog` - Apparently not possible to get a list of people that received the message either?

Comment: Can anyone help please?

Comment: You will only get the app-scoped user ids for friends that are users of your app also already – so if your user invites a friend that is not a user of your app already, you won’t have the friend’s id available to begin with.

Comment: Okay that's a shame.
How can I then track when an invited FB friend log's in with Facebook, and add him to the event that he was invited to?

Comment: If you are not using any of the “official” invite methods, but a share or private message only – then easiest by having your users share/send a link containing a special tracking code in the first place. (Anything else would require additional permissions, like `read_mailbox` to check send message, and that you will definitively not get approved in review.)